# How to fetch entries that are not common in 2 columns in google spread sheets

Tags: sql, google-sheets

How to fetch entries that are not common in 2 columns in google spread sheets using QUERY(). Note that each columns has only unique entries.

Also note that I'm not working on excel, But on google sheets, However a SQL query might be helpful as sheets support QUERY.

Eg:

```
G   H
a   a 
b   c
ca  cx
d   d
e   l
f   b
```

Output must be:

```
c
ca
cx
e
f
l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in columns G and H (starting in row2), try

```
=query(ArrayFormula(query({G2:G;H2:H}&{"",""}, "Select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <>'' group by Col1")), "Select Col1 where Col2 < 2")
```

Alternatively, FILTER should also work

```
={filter(G2:G8, isna(match(G2:G8,H2:H8,0))); filter(H2:H8, isna(match(H2:H8,G2:G8,0)))}
```